# How to pad and unpad std::string in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the following in VS2019:

1. Read data from the command window as a string
2. Pad data to 128 bytes.
3. Encrypt data using OpenSSL (I know that the OpenSSL applies the padding by itself but due to the structure of my simulator I need additional padding before starting the encryption. Because my system only works with a fixed length of data and I prefer not to make changes in that part.)
4. Sends data for the receiver through the IP Tunnel.
5. The receiver will decrypt the data and then unpad the data.

All the steps are done except that I don't know how to pad and unpad. I appreciate your valuable comments.

Here are some of my codes:

```
bool LoadFromCommandWindow::runBlock(void) {

std::cout << "Enter your message: ";
std::getline(std::cin, plainData);

if (plainData.length() == 0) return false;


for (auto k : outputSignals)  // This part saves the data into buffer and then sent for Rx
{
    k->bufferPut((std::byte*) &plainData, plainData.length());
}

return true;
```

}

**Update:** For padding, I found this function:

```
void padTo(std::string& str, const size_t num, const char paddingChar = '\0') 
if (num > str.size())
str.insert(str.size(), num - str.size(), paddingChar);
```

Now how can I unpad it on the Rx side?

Comment: Just check the length()/size() of the string and whenever it's below 128 you add trailing spaces (or a special character that you know well and don't expect being used in the input) until it matches the desired size?

Comment: @ AlexG What about unpadding? Because on the receiver side I don't have any information about the original length of the data. Thanx.

Comment: Well, assuming you added trailing characters, you can extract the substring starting from index 0 to the first instance of that character. Another less efficient way is to use std::string::replace and replace all the occurences with an empty string.

Comment: Pad it with `'\0'` and remove it on the other side

Comment: Can you please write some example codes for unpadding? Thanx.

Comment: `str = str.substr(0, str.length() - unpad_amount)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can pad and unpad a `std::string`.

```
inline void padTo(std::string& str, size_t num, char paddingChar = '\0') {
    str.append(num - str.length() % num, paddingChar);
}

inline void unpad(std::string& str, char paddingChar = '\0') {
    size_t n = str.length();
    while (n != 0 && str[n-1] == paddingChar)
        n--;
    str.resize(n);
}
```

Beware that `\0` characters are invisible when printed. When debugging use a different character.

`\0` should be sufficient to pad text messages. For padding binary data, a popular algorithm is [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7).

Comment: @ rustyx Thank you so much. For now, I am padding text messages, however, I should proceed with binary data as well. Although I searched a lot, I could not find any example code for implementing PKCS#7. If you know any resources, I would be grateful.